How can I get the GNU linker to generate farcall stubs to assembler functions?
I have an application targeting ARM Cortex M0+ MCU, written primarily in C++ but using a FPU library written in assembler. For performance reasons I need to run these functions in RAM, which means that when functions in flash memory call them it is necessary to use a farcall stub because the usual BL instruction can't cover the address difference between flash and RAM. For calls to code compiled from C++ but assigned to RAM, the linker generates these stubs automatically. But for calls to the functions in my assembler file, it doesn't.
I have read that "Farcalls stubs insertion is fully supported for the ARM-EABI target only, because it relies on object files properties not present otherwise.". I've also discovered that the GNU assembler has a directive ".eabi_attribute" so my guess is that I need to use this directive in my assembler file somehow to enable the linker to generate farcall stubs to its function entry points when necessary. But I've found no guidance on what attributes to specify.
Can anyone help me to get this working? My assembler file already has ".cpu cortex-m0plus" and ".thumb" directives near the start.

Look at generated assembly code for a sample C++ function using gcc -S. That should provide a clue what you need to do.

Possible duplicate: ARM Elf attributes

The mechanism to do this is to use 'C++' function prototypes of the ARM assembler.  Yes, your assembler is the target of the long call, but the code must be generated in the caller.
For example,
      void f () __attribute__ ((longcall));


long_call
short_call
These attributes specify how a particular
function is called. These attributes override the -mlong-calls (see
ARM Options) command-line switch and #pragma long_calls settings. For
ARM, the long_call attribute indicates that the function might be far
away from the call site and require a different (more expensive)
calling sequence. The short_call attribute always places the offset to
the function from the call site into the ‘BL’ instruction directly.

While it is feasible that you can do this with .eabi_attribute, this is a more direct note to the compiler and you should be generating these header files anyway to provide protection against argument mismatch between the assembler and 'C++'.

The 'linker' solution is great for partitioning existing C/C++ code to different memory locations.  For example, you put 'zlib' somewhere else.  Since you are coding in assembler, you have already crossed the rubicon to create/modify the interface between the two.  You need the headers anyway.  You should wrap this functionality is a macro or whatever mechanics you find suitable to indicates these are assembler functions located at an alternate (distant) memory location.

Thanks for your solution, I didn't realise that 'longcall' could be specified as an attribute. However this would mean that when I call these functions from time-critical C++ code that I have have also placed in RAM, a long call will always be used whereas a short call would be more efficient. A further complication is that some of these functions override standard library functions using the linker -wrap option, and I can't change those functions to 'longcall'.

You can incrementally link and/or conditionally compile.  Ie, your RAM C++ code can call directly if not compiled with the longcall attribute. You can wrap built-in functionality inside a C++ RAM function, but really you need to partition.  Having an automatic linker solution will not result in better speed as in some cases, the longcall could be as much overhead as the function.  You can also have multiple versions with partial linking including veneers for builtins.

The linker NOCROSSREFS_TO() can be helpful to ensure you do not have jumps back and forth (it seems to defeat your purpose). cally or many other alternatives can help to isolate call hierarchies. Alternate use cases are 'RAM' code for reprogramming flash, etc.  This pattern is fairly established.  You want to minimize coupling.  I think it is a mistake to assume all builtin's placed here will be a benefit.

Another method is to use function pointers/addresses.  Yes, this has some overhead, but since you use C++, it maybe minimal effort (and very little overhead) with virtual.  You need to isolate callers of time critical built-ins for this to work.  So, alot depends on the code base as to what solution is best.  The .eabi_attribute is least effort, but will probably not result in a huge performance gain.

I resolved it by looking at the assembler code generated by gcc for one of my C++ modules and adding the directives I found at the start to my assembler source. Thanks @Jester for suggesting the same thing. The directives I added after the existing .cpu cortex-m0plus were:
.arch armv6s-m
.fpu softvfp
.eabi_attribute 20, 1  # Tag_ABI_FP_denormal, (=20)
.eabi_attribute 21, 1  # Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions, (=21)
.eabi_attribute 23, 3  # Tag_ABI_FP_number_model, (=23)
.eabi_attribute 24, 1  # Tag_ABI_align_needed, (=24)
.eabi_attribute 25, 1  # Tag_ABI_align_preserved, (=25)
.eabi_attribute 26, 1  # Tag_ABI_enum_size, (=26), uleb128
.eabi_attribute 30, 2  # Tag_ABI_optimization_goals, (=30)
.eabi_attribute 34, 0  # Tag_CPU_unaligned_access, (=34)
.eabi_attribute 38, 1  # Tag_ABI_FP_16bit_format (=38)
.eabi_attribute 18, 4  # Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t, (=18), uleb128

Along with ensuring that all the entry points were preceded by .thumb_func (they already were) and adding a type declaration for each entry point (e.g. .type fastSqrtf %function) this appears to be sufficient for the linker to generate the correct farcall stubs from C++ code running from flash memory, while allowing direct calls from C++ code running in RAM.

Not sure which EABI attribute solved your issue.  According to ARM attribute doc  many are unrelated to your issue and could cause un-intended consequences.  Perhaps I have interpreted the information incorrectly.

This TI Link also seems to confirm the attribute values to name seem correct.  If this is actually solving the issue, I think the align/unalign are most likely solving the issue.  However, none of them seem directly related to 'longcall', so if they solve the issue, they are un-intended side effects and could change with different versions of the tooling.

@artless noise thanks for the link, I had searched for documentation about ARM attributes but I hadn't found that one.
